# floating larger image outside of div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Got a problem, some of you might be able to help me with.
Unlike most of the entries i've found on the subject, i am looking for a solution where i can float a larger image inside a div outside of the div.

It works in every browser except IE7, see the link, it's a bit hard to explain but you can see that ie7 centers the image insted of floating it right.

I need it because i have a 2 col layout where the right col needs to have an image there potentially could be underneath the left col.

position:absolute is not an option..

Hope somebody can help.

http://jsfiddle.net/J3NV6/2/

Comment: You want to float: right the <img src="http://deling.pumpthejuice.com/overflow_image.jpg" /> outside the <div class="overflow-image"> ?

Comment: Jep, so that the image is outside the div

Answer (score 1):

You could float the image relative to a wrapper or container, with something like

```
#wrap img.YourImage {
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's a way of solving it, but that requires, that you know the size of the image, it's for a CMS, so the client could upload a image with x width.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this just before closing the div

```
<div style="clear:both; height:0px; font-size:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
```